# Missing Hive Execution Jar Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, bigdata

I know this is a repeat question but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004172/missing-hive-execution-jar-usr-local-hadoop-hive-lib-hive-exec-jar) on stackoverflow did not solved my problem. When i try to run Hive I get following error :

```
 Pawandeep-Singh-2:apache-hive-1.1.1-bin PawandeepSingh1$ bin/hive

 readlink: illegal option -- f

 usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]

 Missing Hive Execution Jar: /usr/local/Cellar/hive/apache-hive-1.1.1-bin/lib/hive-exec-*.jar
```

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here or if you could provide the link to the tutorial from where you installed Hive.

Thank you..

Comment: Post the result for `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/hive/apache-hive-1.1.1-bin/lib` in your question.

Comment: My Hive installation path is /usr/local/hive. But missing library is pointing to /usr/local/Cellar/hive/apache-hive-1.1.1-bin/lib. Why is that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks finally my friend solved the problem and now hive is running. Actually in Mac you have to use .profile file to set the path for hive installation instead of .bash_profile or .bashrc files.

Answer (score 2):

Download the jar manually from this link..
[click here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-exec/0.13.0/hive-exec-0.13.0.jar)

put the jar into /usr/local/Cellar/hive/apache-hive-1.1.1-bin/lib folder.
Check if this solves your problem....

Comment: Thanks for reply Aman. My Hive installation path is /usr/local/hive. But missing library is pointing to /usr/local/Cellar/hive/apache-hive-1.1.1-bin/lib and the jar file you mentioned here is already in my lib folder of /usr/local/hive/lib.