# Missing Hive Execution Jar: /usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-exec-*.jar

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-14.04

While running hive I'm getting following error

```
Missing Hive Execution Jar: /usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-exec-*.jar
```

Seen all related posts like 
[Missing Hive Execution Jar: /usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-exec-*.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004172/missing-hive-execution-jar-usr-local-hadoop-hive-lib-hive-exec-jar)

But didnt help..!! Tried almost everything

Followed steps from here to install
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Hive_Install_On_Ubuntu_16_04.php

Here is my all settings

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END

#PIG VARIABLES
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/bin
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0
export PIG_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/pig/pig-0.16.0/conf

#HIVE VARIABLES
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/*:.
```

In this dir /usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib
Following jars are also available

```
- hive-exec-2.1.1.jar
- hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful...!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if $HIVE_HOME is pointing to the right folder.  You probably have it spelled wrong or are pointing to a version of HIVE that you no longer have installed in that local.